# Concise notation for sum of product of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, notation, combinations

Assume I have a collection of elements $(x_{ij})_{i \in I, j\in J }$. I want to express in a concise notation the sum of the product of the combinations, where one of the elements is left out from each term of the product.

To clarify, I will make the following example with $I = J = \{1,2\}$. I want to write the following expression in a concise form

$$
x_{11}x_{12}x_{21} + x_{11}x_{22}x_{12} + x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}+ x_{11}x_{21}x_{22}, 
$$
i.e., a sum of products of all combinations over $I$ and $J$ where one of the elements is left out.

How to do it for a generic $I$ and $J$? I tried to write it as a sum of products but I am not very familiar with combinations.

Comment: Are you not missing $x_{11}x_{21}x_{22}$ from the sum in your example?  Assuming none are zero, note that these are $\frac{x_{11}x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}}{x_{11}}+\frac{x_{11}x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}}{x_{12}}+\frac{x_{11}x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}}{x_{21}}+\frac{x_{11}x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}}{x_{22}}$

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll update the question

Comment: As for missing a term in a sum or product... I recall Hatcher using a notation in his book on Algebraic Topology along the lines of $\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots \sigma_{i-1}\hat{\sigma_i}\sigma_{i+1}\cdots \sigma_n$ with the hat over $\sigma_i$ to signify that $\sigma_i$ was missing from the product and using it in expressions like $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots \sigma_{i-1}\hat{\sigma_i}\sigma_{i+1}\cdots \sigma_n$.  I can't say I've seen the notation outside of that text personally, but he explained the notation and you could do the same.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I was wondering if there was any way to express it as $\sum\prod$ in any way.

Comment: Reference to where in Hatcher's book this was introduced: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf in section 2.1 on Simplicial and Singular Homology on page 105 second paragraph reading "*As one can see in the next figure, the boundary of the $n$-simplex $[v_0,\dots,v_n]$ consists of the various $(n-1)$-dimensional simplicies $[v_0,\dots,\hat{v}_i,\dots,v_n]$ where the 'hat' symbol $\hat{~}$ over $v_i$ indicates that this vertex is deleted from the sequence $v_0,\dots,v_n$.  In terms of chains...*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial?wprov=sfla1). For your example the notation is $$e_3(x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{21}, x_{22})$$ and I imagine nobody would object if you abbreviated this to $$e_3(x_{11}\ldots x_{22})$$ or $$e_3(x_{ij}).$$